# Move or copy some relationship column to the root

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

so i have this eloquent

```
$table_data = article::with('comments','authors','categories')->get();
```

and it will return this kind of output

```
id:"169"
title:"test"
content:"test content"
{id: 178, id_article: 169, id_tempat: 1, id_bidang: null,…}
{id: 176, id_article: 169, name: "Pendidikan ", tingkat: 8, tempat: "IKIP PGRI Pontinak",…}
created_at:"2018-02-10 01:50:06"
updated_at:"2018-02-10 01:50:06"
```

so like say i want to pull out `name:"pendidikan"` which is if i want to access it need to use `$table.categories.name` but i want to just put it on the root as `categories_name:"pendidikan"` so it will be

```
id:"169"
title:"test"
content:"test content"
categories_name:"pendidikan"
{id: 178, id_article: 169, id_tempat: 1, id_bidang: null,…}
{id: 176, id_article: 169, name: "Pendidikan ", tingkat: 8, tempat: "IKIP PGRI Pontinak",…}
created_at:"2018-02-10 01:50:06"
updated_at:"2018-02-10 01:50:06"
```

so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$categories_name = $table_data->categories->name;
```

Comment: i want to avoid it... and put those $table_data->categories->name; to be $table_data->categories_name; something like doing SELECT AS